# Wait unlill an ajax request is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

There is a link on a page. I want to send an ajax request when an user click on. And only after (when an ajax request is done) that they should be redirected to a page this link refers to.

How can I do that?

Comment: Redirect user in the XHR success callback that's fired on `readyState === 4`.

Comment: How do I make an user stay (no redirection) on a page until that?

Comment: use event.preventDefault() in your click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML something like this:

```
<a id="myAjaxLink" href="http://www.google.com">Click here</a>
```

And the JavaSCript something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myAjaxLink").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: someUrl,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                window.location = $("#myAjaxLink").attr("href");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
    });
});
```